# OpenClipboard crashes with CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPEN

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a problem with opening clipboard multiple times. It opens up fine on the first call, however, my program needs to access the clipboard several times, but shuts down on the second call of `OpenClipboard(NULL)` with the `CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPEN` error).

This is a function that opens the clipboard

```
    void Translator::process_copied()
    {
       //cout << "processing" << endl;

       if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
       {
           HANDLE clip;
           clip = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);
           Relayout((WCHAR*)clip);
 
           HANDLE res = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, sizeof(WCHAR)*wcslen((WCHAR*)clip)+1);
           res = clip;
           EmptyClipboard();
           SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, res);       
           CloseClipboard();
       }
       else
       {
           std::cout << GetLastError();
           //throw clipboard_did_not_open;
           //cout << "error in opening clipboard" << endl;
       }
   }
```

I suspect that the problem appears in the `SetClipboardData()` function, because if I remove it, clipboard doesn't have any problem opening multiple times. The same goes to `res = clip;` line.

I am new to WinAPI and C++ in general, so I apologize if my question is silly.

Comment: _"...If an application calls OpenClipboard with hwnd set to NULL, EmptyClipboard sets the clipboard owner to NULL; this causes SetClipboardData to fail...."_  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-openclipboard

Comment: thank you for your reply. However, I have already tried to open the clipboard with GetForegroundWindow as the parameter, and it didn't solve the problem. Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to call OleInitialize before any clipboard operation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ole2/nf-ole2-oleinitialize#remarks

Comment: I have just added it, thanks for your suggestion. But it didn't solve the problem, unfortunately :(

Comment: What is the purpose of the `res = clip;` line? Smells funny, to me.

Comment: You cannot open the clipboard passing it the window handle of a random window owned by a random thread. Unless, of course, you want some random window to become the clipboard owner. At which point it is unreasonable to assume that your thread can perform operations that require clipboard ownership.

Comment: @AdrianMole In this line I wanted to pass the value of the clip pointer to allocated memory. I have not found the propper way of doing it for a WCHAR pointer, so I ended up doing it this way, which is wrong I assume. If you could suggest a better and more propper way for such opperation, I would be grateful.(btw, everything seems to work just fine on the first pass, so it's just the clipboard which does not close properly, I suspect)

Comment: @IInspectable I think I got what you mean. So I need to open the clipboard, passing it a handle of my program's window in order to set the clipboard data whatever I need. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When storing a memory block on the clipboard, the `HANDLE` given to `SetClipboardData()` *must* be allocated with the `GMEM_MOVEABLE` flag, per the [`SetClipboardData()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboarddata):

> If the `hMem` parameter identifies a memory object, the object must have been allocated using the [GlobalAlloc] function with the `GMEM_MOVEABLE` flag.

As such, you *must* call `GlobalLock()` on the `HANDLE` returned by `GetClipboardData()` in order to access the data, per the [`GlobalAlloc()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globalalloc):

> GMEM_MOVEABLE
> 0x0002
>
> Allocates movable memory. Memory blocks are never moved in physical memory, but they can be moved within the default heap.
>
> The return value is a handle to the memory object. **To translate the handle into a pointer, use the GlobalLock function.**

Don't just type-cast the `HANDLE` as-is, like you can for a memory object allocated with the `GMEM_FIXED` flag.

You are also not putting any character data in the `res` memory that you allocate with `GlobalAlloc()`. Which is moot, since you are not putting your allocated memory on the clipboard at all, you are actually putting the original `HANDLE` from `GetClipboardData()` back onto the Clipboard, and then leaking your `res` memory.

Try something more like this instead:

```
void Translator::process_copied()
{
    //cout << "processing" << endl;

    HWND hwnd = ...; // a window that YOU own

    if (OpenClipboard(hwnd))
    {
        HANDLE clip = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);
        if (clip)
        {
            WCHAR *text = (WCHAR*) GlobalLock(clip);

            Relayout(text);

            HANDLE res = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVABLE, (wcslen(text)+1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
            if (res)
            {
                WCHAR *newText = (WCHAR*) GlobalLock(res);

                // put characters in newText as needed...
                wcscpy(newText, text);

                GlobalUnlock(res);
                GlobalUnlock(clip);

                EmptyClipboard();
                if (!SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, res))
                {
                    std::cout << GetLastError();
                    GlobalFree(res);
                    //throw clipboard_did_not_set;
                    //cout << "error in setting clipboard data" << endl;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << GetLastError();
                //throw global_memory_not_allocated;
                //cout << "error in allocating memory" << endl;

                GlobalUnlock(clip);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << GetLastError();
            //throw clipboard_data_not_get;
            //cout << "error in getting clipboard data" << endl;
        }

        CloseClipboard();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << GetLastError();
        //throw clipboard_did_not_open;
        //cout << "error in opening clipboard" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are my savior. Thank you a lot! Everything worked just fine.

(btw, i deleted comment about `GMEM_MOVEABLE`, it was my fail.)